# BluezV5.42 DBUS C API for BLE?

Tags: c++, linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I have developed BLE application for `openwrt` using `BLUEZV5.30`. I was able to create the application by extracting source code `gatttool` and `hcitool`. I have also added few more functionality then provided by these tools (like reading `rssi`).

However, i have upgraded my `bluez` stack to `5.42` and i am planning to use `DBUS` interface for all BLE related operations. The functionality i want:

1. Reading RSSI
2. Connecting and Disconnecting
3. Bonding
4. Pairing
5. Deleting Bonding information
6. Discovery
7. Scanning
8. Advertising
9. Write/Reading to Characteristics
10. Notifications and Indications

I was able to perform all the above operations (except bonding and pairing) using my code written in C++. However, due to some issues with my existing code and inability to pair/bond, i want to migrate to dbus interface. However, i am not sure about the bugs in `BLUEZ DBUS API` and functionality provided by the APIs. I have read this [API Doc](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc) but it didn't give any clear picture of DBUS interface.

My question is I am not sure if i can get all of the required functionality with `dbus api`? I have read the documentation (bluez dbus api) but i am still not sure.

Comment: I have edited my questioln

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you mention in the other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808453/bluez-5-30-d-bus-gatt-api-simply-discover-and-connect-to-a-ble-device-in-c/36919742?noredirect=1#comment74210660_36919742) I updated [gattlib](https://github.com/labapart/gattlib/) to support Bluez DBUS API.
`gattlib` is written in C. If you do not want to use it looking at its code should help you to progress.

Since Bluez v5.42, [GATT D-BUS API is not longer mark as experimental](http://www.bluez.org/release-of-bluez-5-42/).

The DBUS API is described here: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc. There are also (python) [examples](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test) that demonstrate the API.

- [Reading RSSI](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/device-api.txt)
- [Connecting and Disconnecting](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/device-api.txt)
- [Pairing](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/device-api.txt)
- [Discovery](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt)
- [Scanning](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt)
- [Advertising](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/advertising-api.txt)
- [Write/Reading to Characteristics](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt)
- [Notifications and Indications](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt)
- Bonding and Deleting Bonding information: it looks it is transparent when [using DBUS API](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-bluetooth/msg47687.html).

Comment: Looks like advertising is still experiemental

Comment: How can i pair and not bond? I can't see any api?

Comment: That's right advertising is still experimental. I am using it at the moment and it seems to work (obvisously with the bluez with the experimental flag `-E`).  
I am not sure about pair and not bond. Bluez mailing-list is quite responsive.

Comment: Thank you for writing this. :) I tried different LE python libraries which use one or other interface to Bluez and they all have one or other issue (or are abandoned). This seems like the only method of interfacing Bluez which makes sense to me.